# Number of Digits in System.nanoTime()

Tags: java

How many digits `System.nanoTime()` produce. Whether these digits are fixed or can vary in count?

Thanks

Comment: A long number doesn't have a fixed number of digits, a fixed memory size, yes, but not a fixed number of digits. It looks like you may be confusing a String representation of a number with the number itself.

Comment: Most of the time its 14. :P  System.out.println(String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()).length());

Comment: Thanks I am getting the output 369356930542823 . I think this depends upon JVM.But Can you advice how this gets drive. And Getting 18 digits(String Rep) on other machine.

Comment: If you want to look at the string representation, it can go through `0` (min digits) to `2^63-1 = 9223372036854775807` (max digits)(292 years in nanoseconds)

Comment: Again, it's a long. Look up Long.MAX_VALUE please.

Comment: Thanks Long.MAX_VALUE prints 9223372036854775807. It means this is the maximum.

Comment: Last thing, will System.nanoTime() will return +ve always?

Answer (score 4):

`System.nanotime` returns a high-resolution clock value from your system. It does not have any kind of defined interpretation other than that if you take the *difference* between the return value from two separate calls to `System.nanotime`, you will get an approximate number of nanoseconds that elapsed between those calls.

So the number of digits is not fixed, because there is no specific format for `System.nanotime`'s value, and there is no meaningful way to interpret it. Only use the difference between two calls to `System.nanotime`.

Comment: Will System.nanoTime() will positive always?

Comment: That is not guaranteed; in fact, the documentation explicitly says that values may be negative. Again, you cannot make any expectations on its value.